# Look up column in csv file and enter value in corresponding column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, yfinance

The following code works well, but it does not look up anything from a csv file.  Symbols must be entered manually ('MSFT','AAPL','GOOG') in order for values to be retrieved (asOfDate & PbRatio).  There are about 300,000 symbols.

```
import pandas as pd
from yahooquery import Ticker

symbols = ['MSFT','AAPL','GOOG']

header = ["asOfDate","PbRatio"]
           
for tick in symbols:
    faang = Ticker(tick)
    faang.valuation_measures
    df = faang.valuation_measures
    try:
        for column_name in header :
            if column_name  not in df.columns:
                df.loc[:,column_name  ] = None
        #Missing columns set to None.
        df = df[df['PbRatio'].notna()]
        df = df[df['asOfDate'] == df['asOfDate'].max()]
        df.to_csv('Output.csv', mode='a', index=True, header=False, columns=header)
    except AttributeError:
        continue
```

The csv file looks like this:

[image]

The desired result is this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can create list of dictionaries first and then create file in last step:

```
from yahooquery import Ticker
symbols = ['MSFT','AAPL','GOOG']

#symbols = pd.read_csv('file', names=['symbol']).squeeze()
header = ["asOfDate","PbRatio"]
      
dfs = []     
for tick in symbols:
    faang = Ticker(tick)
    faang.valuation_measures
    df = faang.valuation_measures
    try:
        #Missing columns set to None.
        df.loc[:, pd.Index(header).difference(df.columns, sort=False)] = None

        df = df[df['PbRatio'].notna()]
        dfs.append(df.loc[df['asOfDate'] == df['asOfDate'].max(), header])
        # print (df)
        
    except AttributeError:
        continue
   
out = pd.concat(dfs)
print (out)
         asOfDate    PbRatio
symbol                      
MSFT   2023-03-06  10.440819
AAPL   2023-03-06  42.905318
GOOG   2023-03-06   4.778925

out.to_csv('Output.csv', index=True)
```

Comment: thank you :).  I was trying to get rid of this line of code `symbols = ['MSFT','AAPL','GOOG']` and replace it with something that looks up the Ticker column of the csv file instead.

Comment: @HTMLHelpMe - So need `symbols = pd.read_csv('file', names=['symbol']).squeeze()` ?

Comment: Thank you, @jezreail.  I will try this in the morning and post the results.  Have a great night.

Comment: thanks so much @jezrael.  When I use the following sample csv: `symbol,asOfDate,PbRatio
AI,,
BA,,
AAL,,
MA,,
AA,,
AG,,
APA,,
AR,,
PAA,,
EA,,
AM,,
AAP,,
AU,,
UA,,
HA,,
`, the output is: `symbol,asOfDate,PbRatio
APA,2023-03-01,29.132563
All,2023-03-06,2.167099
L,2023-03-06,0.987286
`.  But two of those symbols aren't in there.  Also, since it is 300,000 symbols the connection can break, so I was trying to get it to append results to the csv file it is reading and continue where it left off if the connection stalls or PC turns off, etc.

Comment: @HTMLHelpMe - Understand. So if use `symbols = pd.read_csv('file', names=['symbol']).squeeze()` missing 2 symbols, but if use `reader = csv.DictReader(file)` not missing? `symbols` ouput are different in both approaches? It is weird, no idea why

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me.

```
import pandas as pd
from yahooquery import Ticker

# Read the list of tickers.
symbols = []
with open("SymbolList.csv", "r") as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)  # This will save the values in the very top of the csv file as header so it will skip a line
    for row in reader:
        symbol = row["symbol"]
        symbols.append(symbol)

header = ["asOfDate","PbRatio"]
           
for tick in symbols:
    faang = Ticker(tick)
    faang.valuation_measures
    df = faang.valuation_measures
    try:
        for column_name in header :
            if column_name  not in df.columns:
                df.loc[:,column_name  ] = None
        #Missing columns set to None.
        df = df[df['PbRatio'].notna()]
        df = df[df['asOfDate'] == df['asOfDate'].max()]
        df.to_csv('Output.csv', mode='a', index=True, header=False, columns=header)
    except AttributeError:
        continue
```